# const ok, but not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, constexpr

With a `constexpr`-specified function `foo_constexpr` I have code such as shown below:

```
const auto x = foo_constexpr(y);
static_assert(x==0);
```

Under which circumstances could the code then fail to compile, when the declaration of `x` is changed to `constexpr`? (After all, `x` must already be a constant expression for use in the `static_assert`.) That is:

```
constexpr auto x = foo_constexpr(y);
static_assert(x==0);
```

Comment: What about `y`? Even if the function is `constexpr` it can still be called at runtime with a runtime value.

Comment: Yes, but `foo_constexpr` can still be part of a constant expression in that case: as long as it doesn't use the value of `y` when calculating the result.

Comment: The point of the comment was that in order to give a precise answer you need to specify what `y` is and how it's used.

Answer (score 8):

In *general*, it can fail to compile when the execution of `foo_constexpr` violates a requirement of constant expressions. Remember, a `constexpr` function is not a function that is always a constant expression. But rather it is a function that can produce a constant expression for at lease one input! That's it.

So if we were to write this perfectly legal function:

```
constexpr int foo_constexpr(int y) {
  return y < 10 ? 2*y : std::rand();
}
```

Then we'll get:

```
constexpr int y = 10;
const     auto x1 = foo_constexpr(y); // valid, execution time constant
constexpr auto x2 = foo_constexpr(y); // invalid, calls std::rand
```

But of course, if `x` is already usable in a constant expression (such as a static assertion), changing to `constexpr` cannot cause a failure to occur.

Comment: Thanks. I have it that it does fail when I change to `constexpr`. Alas I've not yet been able to reduce the code to something useful to share.

Comment: @user2023370 - Reducing it would help. But if your use case really involves `static_assert` and just switching `const` to `constexpr` causes failure, then there's potential from something fishy here.